# Convert epub file to pdf : are there new solutions with a high quality converting?

Tags: pdf, printing, conversion, epub

I would like if threre are new solutions to convert with high-quality an EPUB file to get a PDF.

I read the following post which tells that best converting is performed with "calibre" :

[convert epub to pdf with original (print) formatting?](https://superuser.com/questions/909415/convert-epub-to-pdf-with-original-print-formatting)

I tried this solution with "calibre" but results are bad. a lot of text is bad spaced in the output PDF. I illustrate below this :

1. EPUB original

[image: good formatting]

2. PDF output

[image: bad formatting]

I show you here only one of the first pages of my EPUB book, actually, there are a lot of errors like that.

To generate the output PDF, I have used the "print" option in ebook-viewer of calibre.

Coul anyone tell me if there are currently other solutions to convert EPUB file to PDF file with a high quality about text formatting and equations ?

Or to summarize, what is the state of the art for EPUB-PDF conversion ?

Regards

Comment: The quality of EPUB -> PDF conversion depends on the settings, e.g. font choices etc.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik ok but which settings have I got to take to get a good quality ? Do you think my problem illustrated above comes from size of fonts or font choices (I didn't change anything for this conversion, only default parameters) ? thanks